# how do I sync user token in multi dispatcher setting

Tags: authentication, aem, hmac

Seeking your advise on best practice on the below two use cases :
1st Use case:
I have set up of two Dispatchers (D1 and D2)and two publishers(P1 and P2) with TarMK. D1 always send requests to P1 and D2 always send requests to P2. Load balancer sends request to either D1 or D2.

2nd User case:
I've another setup where D1 can send request either P1 or P2 and D2 can send request either P1 or P2. Load balancer sends request to either D1 or D2.

In this application user token is created on user successful authentication. This token is created based on key located at /etc/key. The key located under /etc/key is different for both P1 and P2.

Given this set-up, a user is logged in to P1 and if P1 goes down then 
1)How can I redirect user to P2 without asking user to login. 
2)How can I replicate user token to P2?

I do not want to use revers replication. What is the best practice of such design? Do I need to keep same key /etc/key in both P1 and P2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to keep same key /etc/key in both P1 and P2?

Short answer: **Yes**

**Details**

AEM uses [Encapsulated Tokens](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/administer/security/encapsulated-token.html) to support authenticated users across publisher farms.

Both of your scenarios to use one dispatcher per publisher or cluster publishers across each dispatcher should work in case of failure if you follow the recommendation of synchronising the HMAC key across all your publishers in the cluster.

This can be achieved by following the instructions [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/administer/security/encapsulated-token.html#Configuring%20the%20Encapsulated%20Token)

AEM is designed around stateless authentication but the token needs to be encrypted and decrypted by same HMAC key which is stored under `/etc/key` path. Unless you synchronise these keys, there is no way for one instance to understand the token from another instance. This is a design/feature of AEM authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i have another case: I have set some attribute in the request object of P1 (D1 sends request to P1), now if D1 sends request to P2, then this attribute will not be available in the request object of P2. In this case Sticky session is recommended or is there other alternate way?

Comment: That's a more complex question to answer in comment as it requires more clarification. I suggest you create a new question so that it can be answered properly.